# SharePoint 2010: How do you add approvers to a specific position in a running Approval Workflow?

Tags: workflow

I am running SharePoint 2010 and working with approval workflows. I found the option in the running workflow to "Add or update approvers of Approval", and that appears to allow me to add users to the running workflow, but only at the end of the list. I need to be able to add a user ahead of the final approver that was in the list when the workflow started. So for example, the workflow is started with:

PersonA -> PersonB -> PersonC

And my users now want to change to this on the running workflow:

PersonA -> PersonB -> PersonD -> PersonC

New user inserted between PersonB and PersonC.

Is this possible? I don't currently have access to SharePoint Designer. I have searched for this, but no luck. I suspect I am just missing something obvious, but I figured I would swallow my pride and ask here! Thanks.

Edit: Just trying to give this one bump. Anyone know about this? Only solution I can find is to reassign PersonC's task to PersonD, and then add PersonC to the end. Not very elegant, but is it the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are really limited with out of the box workflows. You can craft better solutions in places like SPDesigner or VS but just don't have the same tools in the web interface. The work around you propose is about your best option, unfortunately.

Comment: I really appreciate that answer! Thanks for confirming. At least now I know there is not some obvious solution I am missing. I shall continue lobbying for access to SPDesigner ;-)

Comment: No worries. Good luck! SPDesigner is free for whatever its worth. I know some IT depts keep their software installs under lock and key but SPD is a free piece of software from one of the biggest software companies on earth so you would hope that helps the decision. Really powerful too. Custom workflows in SPDesigner open up a whole new world in SharePoint.